# Scheme function to remove atoms?

Tags: scheme

If I have a list like (e q(r))

How would I remove all the atoms and just return (())  ?

Answer (score 3):

Hey, a technique known as tree-recursion is useful for this type of problem.

I agree with the general structure of the Greg's answer, but I think we need to explicitly filter atomic (non-list) values from nested lists.

```
(define (rem-atoms lst)
  (cond
    ((not (list? lst)) lst)
    ((null? lst) (list))
    (else
      (filter
        (lambda (a) (list? a))
        (cons (rem-atoms (car lst))
              (rem-atoms (cdr lst)))))))

(rem-atoms '(f (x y) z () (k ())))  ; --> (() () (()))
(rem-atoms '(f x (y)))              ; --> (())
```

Upon further inspection, a tiny amendment to Greg's good solution also now provides the correct results. Specifically: (not (list? xx)) rather than (not (pair? xx)).

```
(define (rem-atoms lat)
  (cond
    ((null? lat) lat)
    ((not (list? (car lat))) (rem-atoms (cdr lat)))
    (else
      (cons (rem-atoms (car lat))
            (rem-atoms (cdr lat)))))))

(rem-atoms '(f (x y) z () (k ())))  ; --> (() () (()))
(rem-atoms '(f x (y)))              ; --> (())
```

Hmm. I think I like this second version the best!

Note, I'm brand new here, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice solution, and thanks for picking up my mistake. I forgot that empty lists wouldn't work with pair?

Comment: The problem with using `list?` is twofold: 1. It has to traverse the whole list to determine if it's a proper list, every time (whereas `pair?` does not need to traverse), and 2. Do you want to strip out improper lists too? They are not atoms. I think something like `(or (pair? foo) (null? foo))` is more reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

```
(define rem-atoms
 (lambda (lat)
  (cond
    ((null? lat) lat)
    ((not (pair? (car lat))) (rem-atoms (cdr lat)))
    (else
     (cons (rem-atoms (car lat)) (rem-atoms (cdr lat)))))))
```

If the list is empty, return the empty list. If it's an atom (or rather, not a list), just eliminate it. If it's a list, call the function recursively on both the car and the cdr of the list.